# Instantiating instances of classes stored in HashMap

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums, factory

I wanted to created an Enum where each enum object will be mapped to an event, and would have a class associated with each event.
A factory class would return an instance of correct class based on event type. This is what i am trying to do:

Enum:

```
public Enum Event{

  EVENT_1("First Event",EventProcessor1.class);
  private final String eventType;
  private final Class<? extends IEventProcessor> processorClass;
  Event(String eventType, Class<? extends IEventProcessor> processorClass){
  {
    this.eventType = eventType;
    this.processorClass = processorClass;
  }
  // getters setters ignored
  ....
}
```

Factory:

```
public class EventFactory{
  ....
  public static IEventProcessor getEventProcessor(Event e){
    return e.getProcessorClass.newInstance();
  }
  ....
}
```

The line where i create a new instance shows no compilation issues but throws Instantiation Exception. So my questions are:
       Why the Exception?
       Any alternative way to accomplish this?

[IEventProcessor is the interface implemented by all EventProcessor classes]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Show the constructor of an Eventprocessor instance... Are you sure it has a default constructor? Also, you might be interested in the [**Abstract factory pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)...

Comment: Also, the enum name should probably be `EventType` and not `Event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the javadoc for [InstantiationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html)

> Thrown when an application tries to create an instance of a class
> using the newInstance method in class Class, but the specified class
> object cannot be instantiated. The instantiation can fail for a
> variety of reasons including but not limited to:
>
> - the class object
>   represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a
>   primitive type, or
> - void the class has no nullary constructor

You need to check the class, to see if an instance can be created from a public constructor with no arguments.